# Distribution of weighted data

Tags: maximum-likelihood, goodness-of-fit, weighted-sampling, weighted-data

I want to fit a distribution to weighted data, and I have some issues, starting with the parameter estimation. How can I perform the MLE with the WEIGHTED data? The histogram of the weighted data fits clearly a lognormal distribution, does it mean W*X ~ Log-Normal? Is it just perform the estimation with the set {W[i]*X[i]}? (W the weiths, X the data)? Or I should change the 'average'-like expressions for 'weighted average'-like others?
Thanks

Comment: If *weighted data* means some data points are more important than other, the general idea would be to count the important data points multiple times. E.g. if $x_1$ has weight 1 and $x_2$ has weight 2, you could count $x_1$ once and $x_2$ twice. I guess it should not be too difficult to generalize to fractional weights. But I am not sure how to implement this idea efficiently.